# how to download a file from remaining percentage(download left off at first time) in android

Tags: android, url, download

I facing problem with downloading zip file from server means by using Url connection i am able to download a file but my requirement is whenever i downloading that time may internet connection may lost or app may close for some other reason . that time again i need to download that file but not from starting, means if started downloading and 40% download and then connection, then again i need to download that from 40%.
how to do that? i browsed but i did not find my requirement? please any on e can help?

```
 if(new File(filePath).exists()){
                //ucon.disconnect();
             //   ucon.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
                ucon.setRequestMethod("GET");
                ucon.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + new File(filePath).length() + "-");
                inStream.skip(new File(filePath).length());
                ucon.connect();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Range` request of HTTP protocol to request part of the file. 
First you have to send `HEAD` to see if the server you are talking to supports range requests by sending `HEAD` with `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header. 
If server supports it, it will return `200 OK` response and then you can safely send `GET` request with byte offsets in `Range: 10-100` header.

The above GET request will query the server for data starting from 10th byte to 100th byte and if request succeeds, it will return 206 Partial Document response

Comment: i was set ucon.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + new File(filePath).length() + "-");
                    inStream.skip(new File(filePath).length()); and its throwing error and where i need to set head